# Quotes in command line arguments in Eclipse?

Tags: lua, eclipse-cdt

I need to pass something like this to Eclipse CDT:

`-lua 'dofile("path/to/my/file.lua")'`

However, my `argv[2]` ends up without quotes:

`'dofile(path/to/my/file.lua)'`

How can I fix this to keep the quotes?

Comment: I'm not sure, but does it help if you escape the quotes? Like putting `\"` instead of `"`?

Comment: Escaping doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: @pmg and so ? Could you clarify ?

Comment: Clarification: C tag removed as irrelevant

Comment: did you try swapping " and ' ?  `what about 'dofile([[path/to/my/file.lua]])'`